# Check if website is being accessed using ip address or domain name

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

I have an AWS EC2 instance and need to know whether a specific user is accessing the site using the domain (lets say example.com) or the instance static ip (lets say 1.2.3.4).

In the httpd access logs (/var/log/httpd/access_log) I can view logs like the following:

```
1.2.3.4 - user [18/Apr/2018:06:20:18 -0300] "GET /site/path HTTP/1.0" 200 0 "-" "USERAGENT"
```

Is there a way to show url or ip in the /site/path part or another log I should be looking at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the log output for the access log or create an entirely separate log by updating your httpd.conf or apache2.conf file. Adding `%{Host}i%` to the LogFormat should get you what you are looking for.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!